# Does google really pronounce a schwa here as it says rather than an "i"?

Tags: pronunciation, american-accent

When I google "authentic pronunciation" or "enjoy pronunciation", it will show the followings:

[image]

[image]

> However, they don't sound like "tuhk" or "uhn"  to me  as it says (what google pronounces when I click the sound button there), they are still "i" (ɪ in IPA) just with less emphasis. Are they really pronounced by Google as "u"(schwa ə) but somehow as a non-native speaker I can't hear it?

Comment: I have never heard any native speaker say anything like an uh for the en of enjoy, or for the then of authentic. They still sound like a short i like hit or fit.

Comment: @CYC, what is your question? Are you asking why Google has written 'uh' instead of 'i'?

Comment: I'm asking, does google actually say "uh" in the audio (but somehow I can't distinguish it), or it in fact says "i" as I hear.

Comment: It clearly says 'i', not 'uh'.

Comment: Actually, I feel the same problem with Google translate app. I started using Youtube or different apps for the words ambiguous to me. I can't distinguish the sound from audio form all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Having just listened to those examples, you are right, they are definitely pronounced as /ɔːˈθɛntɪk/ and /ɪnˈdʒɔɪ/. I also think those are more common pronunciations, especially of "authentic".

However, there is considerable variation in how those syllables are realized.

In my accent, I think the pronunciation of "enjoy" varies between /ɪnˈdʒɔɪ/ and /nˈdʒɔɪ/, with no initial vowel other than the /n/ sound. A [syllabic consonant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant) like that is often transcribed as a schwa, for example "even" is transcribed as /ˈiːvən/ despite being pronounced as /ˈiːvn/.

Subjectively, I often hear British people use an /ɪ/ where I would use a schwa, for example in "pleases" where they say /ˈpliːzɪz/ rather than my pronunciation of /ˈpliːzəz/.

Comment: nice answer, totally overlooked...